# Scrolling through Table View with embedded Table View Inside a Container View

Tags: ios, uitableview, scrollview, uicontainerview

This is a tableView. The white sections are the tableview cells. In the footer of tableView, I've added a scrollview with 2 containers views embeded with 2 UIViewControllers. These embeded view controllers contains tableView.

[image] [image]

Now I'm having a problem with the scrolling. I'm scrolling the main tableview and as I scroll, I'm changing the height of the table footerview on which the scrollview is added. Now the problem is when I scroll through child view controller, I'm not able to scroll to the top of my main tableView. How should I do it? Is there is demo github project which I can refer to any code?

**EDIT:**

This is how my storyboard looks like:

[image]

I want to implement something like Facebook has implemented. I think they are using tableview with page view controller. How can I achieve this?

[image] [image][image]

Comment: can you explain some more? or maybe provide a screenshot of your storyboard or your code

Comment: @zombie Added a screenshot of the storyboard.

Comment: why do you need a uitableview inside uiscrollview the table itself is a scrollview

Comment: are you trying to implement a paging feature?

Comment: @zombie Yes I'm trying to implement the paging feature with the header view also scrolling vertically. Is there any possible way to implement it?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding - can you show the code for your footer and header views?

Comment: I have updated my question with what I actually want to implement.

Comment: @BhavukJain did you get a solution for this